# Save a file and overwrite it when it exists in Java GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have a button in a toolbar which has to save what I am drawing in a JFrame in Java. It works but it currently acts as a 'Save As' button. I am trying to make it overwrite the file once it is saved without showing a dialog. Can someone help me fix it?

My code:

```
JFileChooser fileChooser2;
this.fileChooser2 = new JFileChooser();
fileChooser2.addChoosableFileFilter(new TxtFilter2());
```

**EDIT**

```
public class TxtFilter2 extends FileFilter
{

    public boolean accept(java.io.File file)
           {
            if (file.isDirectory())
             return true;

            return (file.getName().endsWith("xml"));
           }

          public String getDescription()
           {
            return "Save (*.xml)";
           }

}
```

This is the button itself with the action:

```
if (ev.getActionCommand()=="Save2")
     {
      fileChooser2.setDialogType(JFileChooser.SAVE_DIALOG);
      fileChooser2.setDialogTitle("Save as XML file format");

      res=this.fileChooser2.showSaveDialog(this);
      if (res==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
       {
        this.net.saveToFile(fileChooser2.getSelectedFile().getPath()+".xml");
       } 

     }
```

Comment: ev.getActionCommand()=="Save2"

Comment: `fileChooser2.showSaveDialog(this)` opens a Dialog. If you don't want that, implement some logic, that stores the files location when its saved the first time and if the location is stored, save to it silently.

Comment: You’re showing a JFileChooser dialog… from within your FileFilter?  That is going to cause havoc.  A FileFilter’s job is to return true or false based on whether a file should be displayed.  It should not do anything else.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the file or at least the path to the file in a member variable once the user saves for the first time. This would allow you to recognize whether the drawing has already been saved and allow you to overwrite it.

First you need a field to store the file/path:

```
private File savedFile;
```

then you can use it to overwrite it:

```
if (ev.getActionCommand().equals("Save2")) {
    //Check if the drawing has already been saved, if not open the dialog
    if(this.savedFile == null) {
        fileChooser2.setDialogType(JFileChooser.SAVE_DIALOG);
        fileChooser2.setDialogTitle("Save as XML savedFile format");

        int res = this.fileChooser2.showSaveDialog(this);
        if (res == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            final File selectedFile = fileChooser2.getSelectedFile();
            //Store the selected file in the member variable
            this.savedFile = selectedFile;
            this.net.saveToFile(selectedFile.getPath() + ".xml");
        }
    }else {
        //Use the previously selected file and don't show the dialog
        this.net.saveToFile(this.savedFile.getPath() + ".xml");
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if that's what you want to do and I don't know what exactly your `this.net.saveToFile()` method does but I hope this helps

Comment: It works and it is exactly what I wanted. Thank you!

Comment: @Danny perfect! no problem

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, this is the name of the action I choose when I create the button. I was trying lots of things, so I had to choose different names.

Comment: @Danny: You should never compare Strings this way. The `==` operator checks if two ***references*** are identical which is not what you want to test and which can lead to hard to find code logic errors. Instead you care if the two Strings have the same characters in the same order -- you want a *functional* test of equivalence which is what the `.equals(...)` and `.equalsIgnoreCase(...)` are for. I don't expect you to know this, but scsere is answering your question,, and so should know better, and so it surprises me that he perpetuated this error in his posted code and made no mention of it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels You're right, changed it. Just used the posted code and assumed it's working properly